# Debezium MySQL fails "io.debezium.DebeziumException: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: 'Table xxxx' doesn't exist"

Tags: mysql, debezium

Debezium MySQL connector fails during initial snapshotting.

Error:

```
io.debezium.DebeziumException: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'xxx' doesn't exist
    at io.debezium.pipeline.source.AbstractSnapshotChangeEventSource.execute(AbstractSnapshotChangeEventSource.java:85)
    at io.debezium.pipeline.ChangeEventSourceCoordinator.doSnapshot(ChangeEventSourceCoordinator.java:155)
    at io.debezium.pipeline.ChangeEventSourceCoordinator.executeChangeEventSources(ChangeEventSourceCoordinator.java:137)
    at io.debezium.pipeline.ChangeEventSourceCoordinator.lambda$start$0(ChangeEventSourceCoordinator.java:109)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'xxx' doesn't exist
```

This `xxx` table is not part of `table.include.list`, also its database is not part of `database.include.list`.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that Debezium will try to read **schema of all tables from all databases** during snapshotting, disregarding the `.include.list` setting.

This is done with `SHOW FULL TABLES`. See [link](https://github.com/debezium/debezium/blob/main/debezium-connector-mysql/src/main/java/io/debezium/connector/mysql/MySqlSnapshotChangeEventSource.java).

However, there was one corrupt database, all tables popping up with `SHOW TABLES` but when `SELECT`, `DROP` against them, MySQL says they do not exist.

We created a new table of the same name and dropped it, however `SHOW TABLES` still shows it. So we created new tables for all the tables, they seem to coexist with the corrupted ones even they have identical names!

However it now passed the snapshotting check. This is very strange case considering the MySQL database was managed RDS instance there should be in no way should we be able to mess around and corrupt it.